# Difficulty understanding `Associated Types` in Swift protocol extensions

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

I'm struggling to understand protocols and protocol extensions in swift.

I'm wanting to define a series of protocols that can be applied to a class, along with a set of protocol extensions to provide default implementations.  Example code:

```
// MARK: - Protocols & Protocol Extensions
protocol OutputItem {
    typealias ResultType
    func rawValue() -> ResultType
    // other requirements ...
}

protocol StringOutputItem : OutputItem {}
extension StringOutputItem {
    typealias ResultType = String
    override func rawValue() -> Self.ResultType {
        return "string ouput"
    }
}

protocol IntOutputItem: OutputItem {}
extension IntOutputItem {
    typealias ResultType = Int
    override func rawValue() -> Self.ResultType {
        return 123
    }
}
```

The above override functions for `rawValue()` in the extensions give an error `Ambiguous type name 'ResultType' in 'Self'`.  If I remove `Self`, from `Self.ResultType`, I get the error `'ResultType' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context`.

How do I signal to the protocol extension which type to use for `ResultType`?

My aim is to be able to apply the protocols and their extensions to a class as follows:

```
// MARK: - Base Class
class DataItem {
    // Some base class methods
    func randomMethod() -> String {
        return "some random base class method"
    }
}

// MARK: - Subclasses
class StringItem : DataItem, StringOutputItem {
    // Some subclass methods
}

class AnotherStringItem : DataItem, StringOutputItem {
    // Some subclass methods
}

class IntItem : DataItem, IntOutputItem {
    // Some subclass methods
}
```

So that:

```
let item1 = StringItem()
print(item1.rawValue())         // should give "string output"

let item2 = AnotherStringItem()
print(item2.rawValue())         // should give "string output"

let item3 = IntItem()
print(item3.rawValue())         // should give 123
```

If I'm completely off base with how protocol extensions work to provide default implementations, I'm open ideas of how to achieve the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The Swift compiler infers the type of `ResultType` by the type signatures of the implemented protocol methods. For example, in the following declaration of `StringOutputItem`, the compiler knows that `StringOutputItem`'s `ResultType` is of type `String`, even without an explicit declaration:

```
protocol StringOutputItem: OutputItem {}

extension StringOutputItem {
    func rawValue() -> String {
        return "string output"
    }
}

class StringItem : DataItem, StringOutputItem {}

let item = StringItem()
print(item.rawValue()) // prints "string output"
```

We can explicitly declare the `ResultType` in `StringOutputItem`, which will just ensure that `StringOutputItem` conforms to the `OutputItem` protocol AND implements it with the right type.

To illustrate the type inference of the associated type, let's say that `OutputItem` specifies another method as part of its protocol. If we provide a default implementation whereby the types do not match, the compiler will throw an error indicating that the implementing type does not conform to the protocol.

```
protocol OutputItem {
    typealias ResultType
    func rawValue() -> ResultType
    func printValue(r: ResultType)
}

protocol StringOutputItem: OutputItem {}

extension StringOutputItem {
    func rawValue() -> String {
        return "string output"
    }
    func printValue(r: Int) {  // Should be String
        ...
    }
}

struct Test: StringOutputItem {} // Error: Type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'OutputItem'
```

By explicitly declaring `typealias ResultType = String` in `StringOutputItem`, we are making sure that the correct type is used when implementing the protocol's methods.

```
protocol OutputItem {
    typealias ResultType
    func rawValue() -> ResultType
    func printValue(r: ResultType)
}

protocol StringOutputItem: OutputItem {}

extension StringOutputItem {
    typealias ResultType = String // without this typealias declaration, the program WILL compile since ResultType is inferred to be of type Int
    func rawValue() -> Int {
        return 123
    }
    func printValue(r: Int) {  
        ...
    }
}

struct Test: StringOutputItem {} // Error: Type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'OutputItem'
```